# Swift 4: Downcast callback function issue

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift4

I have an API class for server side connection:

```
class APIClient {

    typealias CompletionHandler = (CodabilityResponse) -> Void

    @discardableResult
    private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route: APIRouter, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> DataRequest {
        return Alamofire.request(route).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            do {
                //print("The response is: \(response.result.value)")
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: response.data!)
                completion(json)
            } catch let err {
                print("Err", err)
            }
        })
    }


    static func login(loginData: LoginRequest, completion: @escaping (LoginResponse) -> Void) {
        performRequest(route: APIRouter.login(loginData: loginData)) { (response) in
            self.commonCompletion(response: response, for: completion)
        }
    }
```

Each response in my application inherit from CodablityResponse protocol, which inherit from Codabilty protocol:

```
protocol Codability: Codable { }

    extension Codability {
        typealias T = Self
        func encode() -> Data? {
            return try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        }

        static func decode(data: Data) -> T? {
            return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
    }

    protocol CodabilityResponse: Codability {

        var status: String { get }
        var errorMessage: [String]? { get }
        var errorCode: Int { get }
    }

    extension CodabilityResponse { }
```

My common completion function is looks like:

```
private static func commonCompletion(response: CodabilityResponse, for commonCompletion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        if response.status == APIStatus.success.rawValue && response.errorCode == APIErrors.OK.rawValue {
            commonCompletion(response)
        }
        else {
            //TODO SHOW ERROR ONLY IN THIS PLACE

        }
    }
```

The problem is in this row `self.commonCompletion(response: response, for: completion)`, it can not downcast from `(LoginResponse)->Void` to `(CodabilityResponse)-> Void` in spite the fact that `LoginResponse` inherits from `CodabilityResponse`
If I add force casting then I get next error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

I broke my head my have no idea what is wrong. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Although the type `LoginResponse` inherits from `CodabilityResponse` and you can therefore return an instance of the former where the latter is specified, it is the type of the completion handler that is the issue.

The type of the completion handler is `(CodabilityResponse)-> Void` which can't be downcast from the unrelated type `(LoginResponse) -> Void`

Instead of

```
static func login(loginData: LoginRequest, completion: @escaping (LoginResponse) -> Void)
```

Use

```
static func login(loginData: LoginRequest, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler)
```

That way `completion` is of the correct type and since `LoginResponse` inherits from `CodabilityResponse` you can pass an instance of it to `commonCompletion`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I will use CompletionHandler instead of (T) -> Void I will get a problem in decode function with Decodable instance of T

Comment: And another question why I get Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred error if CodabilityResponse is Decodable

Comment: Sorry, not sure why I put that in my original answer, I have updated it.